# Modern Opengl Texture Pyramid

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

I am trying to apply an image onto my triangle; however, the result shows that the triangle display as white color. I wonder if it is possibility that my code's color is overwrite the texture.

```
/*Header Inclusions*/
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/Glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

// GLM Math inclusions
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

//include soil
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

using namespace std; // Uses the standard namespace

#define WINDOW_TITLE "Modern OpenGL" // Macro for window title

//Vertex and fragment shader
#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, source) "#version " #Version "\n" #source
#endif


// Variables for window width and height
GLint ShaderProgram, WindowWidth = 800, WindowHeight = 600;
GLuint VBO, VAO, uTexture;
GLfloat degrees = glm::radians(-45.0f);
struct TAttributeTuple
   {
       glm::vec3 v;
       glm::vec2 uv;
   };
/* User-defined Function prototypes to:*/
void UResizeWindow(int,int);
void URenderGraphics(void);
void UCreateShader(void);
void UCreateBuffers(void);
void UGenerateTexture(void);

/* Vertex Shader Source Code*/

const GLchar * vertexShaderSource ="#version 400 core\n"

                   // Vertex data from Vertex Attrib Pointer 0

        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;"

                   // Color data from Vertex Attrib Pointer 1

        "layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;"

        "layout(location = 2 in vec2 vertex_texcoord;"

                   //variable to transfer color data to the fragment shader

        "out vec3 mobileColor;"
        "out vec3 modelPosition"
        "out vec2 vs_texcoord;"
                   //Global variables for the transform matrices

//        "uniform mat4 model;"
//
//        "uniform mat4 view;"
//
//        "uniform mat4 projection;"

        "void main()\n"

        "{\n"

                   // transforms vertices to clip coordinates

        "modelPosition = position;"

        "vs_texcoord = vec2(vertex_texcoord.x, vertex_texcoord.y * 1.0f;"
        // references incoming color data

        "mobileColor = color;"
        "gl_Position =  vec4(position, 1.0f);"

        "}\n";



/* Fragment Shader Source Code*/

const GLchar * fragmentShaderSource ="#version 400 core\n"

        "in vec3 mobileColor;" // Variable to hold incoming color data from vertex shader

        "in vec2 vs_texcoord;"

        "out vec4 gpuColor;"  // Variable to pass color data to the GPU

        "uniform sampler2D uTexture"

        "void main()\n"

        "{\n"

        "gpuColor = texture(uTexture, vs_texcoord) * vec4(mobileColor, 1.0);"

        "}\n";

/* Fragment Shader Source Code */
//main program
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

glutReshapeFunc(UResizeWindow);


glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit()!= GLEW_OK)
    {
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return -1;
    }

    UCreateShader();

    UCreateBuffers();

    UGenerateTexture();

    // Use the Shader program
        glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);


        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color

        glutDisplayFunc(URenderGraphics);

        glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

        glutMainLoop();

        // Destroys Buffer objects once used
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

        return 0;

    }

    /* Resizes the window*/
    void UResizeWindow(int w, int h)
    {
    WindowWidth = w;
        WindowHeight = h;
        glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
     }


     /* Renders graphics */
    void URenderGraphics(void)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable z-depth

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clears the screen

        glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Activate the Vertex Array Object before rendering and transforming them

        // Transforms the object
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // Place the object at the center of the 7i,p9rA
        model = glm::rotate(model, degrees, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f)); // Rotate the object 45 degrees on the XYZ
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)); // Increase the object size by a scale of 2

        // Transforms the camera
        glm::mat4 view;
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f)); //Moves the world 0.5 units on X and -5 units in Z

        // Creates a perspective projection
        glm::mat4 projection;
        projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WindowWidth / (GLfloat)WindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Retrieves and passes transform matrices to the Shader program
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "projection");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glutPostRedisplay();

        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "uTexture"), 0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTexture);

    // Draws the triangles
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0, 36);

        glBindVertexArray(0); // Deactivate the Vertex Array Object

        glutSwapBuffers(); // Flips the the back buffer with the front buffer every frame. Similar to GL FLush

         }

         /*Creates the Shader program*/
         void UCreateShader()
         {

            // Vertex shader
            GLint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // Creates the Vertex Shader
            glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL); // Attaches the Vertex Shader to the source code
            glCompileShader(vertexShader); // Compiles the Vertex Shader

            // Fragment Shader
            GLint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); // Creates the Fragment Shader
            glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);// Attaches the Fragment Shader to the source code
            glCompileShader(fragmentShader); // Compiles the Fragment Shader

            // Shader program
            ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram(); // Creates the Shader program and returns an id
            glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, vertexShader); // Attach Vertex Shader to the Shader program
            glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, fragmentShader);; // Attach Fragment Shader to the Shader program
            glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram); //Link Vertex and Fragment shader, to Shader program

            // Delete the Vertex and Fragment shaders once linked
            glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
            glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

         }


           /*creates the buffer and array object*/
            void UCreateBuffers()
            {
             glm::vec3 top(  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f );
             glm::vec3 p01( -0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
             glm::vec3 p11(  1.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
             glm::vec3 p00(  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
             glm::vec3 p10(  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
                //position and color data
             TAttributeTuple vertices[]
             {
                 { p00, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p10, glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p11, glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
                 { p00, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p11, glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
                 { p01, glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f) },

                 { p00, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p10, glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { top, glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f) },

                 { p10, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p11, glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { top, glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f) },

                 { p11, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p01, glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { top, glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f) },

                 { p01, glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { p00, glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
                 { top, glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f) }
             };


             //Generate buffer id,
                glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
                glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);


             // Activate the Vertex Array Object before binding and setting any VB0s and Vertex Attribute Pointers.
                glBindVertexArray(VAO);

              // Activate the VBO
             glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

             glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
             glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Copy vertices to VBO

             // Set attribute pointer 0 to hold Position data
             glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
             glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Enables vertex attribute

             // Set attribute pointer 2 to hold Color data
              glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
              glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // Enables vertex attribute

             glBindVertexArray(0); // Deactivates the VAC, which is good practice

             }
         /*Generate and load the texture*/
         void UGenerateTexture(){

         glGenTextures(1, &uTexture);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTexture);

         int width = 0,
             height = 0 ;

         unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("./image/bricks.png", &width, &height, NULL, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);



         if(image)
         {
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
             glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
             glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
         }
         else{
             std::cout << "FAIL TO LOAD IMAGE" << "\n";
         }
         glActiveTexture(0);
         SOIL_free_image_data(image);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

[image]

Comment: You never assign to vertex attribute 1 so the `color` values are uninitialized. Multiplying with `vec4(mobileColor, 1.0)` is then not safe, try to remove it. I do not have FreeGlut on hand, so I cannot test your code.

Comment: Your vertex shader doesn't even comüpile, because there is a `)` missing in `layout(location = 2 in vec2 vertex_texcoord;`